# Simple imwrite does not write to file

Tags: matlab

I am trying to manipulate and save an image to file and it doesn't seem to be working from a function.  It does, however, work in the command window.  I have tried save, saveas, fprint, and others with no luck.

```
A = imread('contourSS.jpg'); B = rgb2gray(A);
imwrite(B, 'new_image.gif', 'gif');
```

Nothing shows up in the MATLAB directory when I run this code from a function, but it does show up in the MATLAB directory when I run it from the command window.  Any ideas?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: put a breakpoint on that link to check if it is actually executed.

Comment: If you'll add the function that you use, we might spot what's going wrong.

Comment: sorry I meant "line" not "link"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure the you're saving the file to the correct directory?  Try adding adding `disp(pwd)` to the function, it will display the directory that you are saving too.

Also its generally a good idea to use complete paths when saving a file. Consider changing your code to this:

```
imgDir = /home/user/image;
readfile = fullfile( imgDir, 'contourSS.jpg');
writefile = fullfile( imgDir, 'new_image.gif');

A = imread(readfild); B = rgb2gray(A);
imwrite(B, writefile, 'gif');
```